# Why do state changes before mount cause function execution but don't show on screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**Prelude**

I know that rendering state changes right after the component mounts should be put into a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array to be rendered, for example:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState("one");

useEffect(() => {
  setValue("two");
}, []);
```

**Scenario**

Out of curiosity I created a component (i.e. [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-conditional-usestate-setters-iicz6?file=/src/App.js)) with a global variable `isFirstRender` which checks whether it's the first render to change state for the initial mount of the component:

```js
let isFirstRender = true;

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("one");

  // should only run once at the beginning
  if (isFirstRender) {
    console.log("inside if clause");

    setValue("two");

    isFirstRender = false;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted");
  }, []);

  console.log("-- render --", { value });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Conditional useState setters</h1>
      <p>Value: {value}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Stack Snippet:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

let isFirstRender = true;

/*export default*/ function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("one");
  
    // should only run once at the beginning
    if (isFirstRender) {
        console.log("inside if clause");
    
        setValue("two");
    
        isFirstRender = false;
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("mounted");
    }, []);
  
    console.log("-- render --", { value });
  
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Conditional useState setters</h1>
            <p>Value: {value}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

To my surprise the component function gets invoked and the changed value (`"two"` instead of `"one"`) is visible in the console, but won't render to the screen. It still says `"one"` in the browser.

**Questions**

1. Doesn't the fact that the function is being invoked by the call of the setter function of the `useState` hook mean that the function "does" render with the updated state value?
2. I thought in **React** an invocation of a function component is synonymous of a *render*? Is the time before a component gets mounted an exception to this rule?

Comment: *"To my surprise the component function gets invoked and the changed value ("two" instead of "one") is visible in the console, but won't render to the screen."* I can't replicate that. Are you sure what's in your question is the same as what you had when you thought you saw that? When I use the above, I see exactly what I expect to see -- two renders, with "two" showing on the page.

Comment: I've copied your code into a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). It does show "two" correctly...?

Comment: I added the link to the CodeSandBox which I created to the post (forgot it before - Sorry!): https://codesandbox.io/s/react-conditional-usestate-setters-iicz6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's great, but the way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please copy whatever is different from the CodeSandbox into the Stack Snippet I added for you, so everything here **here on-site**.

Comment: I did peek at the CodeSandbox, and the code looks identical. (And I checked React versions, etc.) You may be looking at a bug in the toolchain there -- CodeSandbox, react-scripts, webpack or whatever it's bundling with, etc. But fundamentally, although that's kind of interesting, since you're breaking one of the main rules of React (don't modify state during render), I wouldn't be too bothered about it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! Yes, I can't find a difference to my CodeSandBox. These different results in different cloud environments is quite puzzling but perhaps gives the hint that the scenario I created here is something out of control of React and thereby out of control of myself as the developer really. So as you're saying I won't be able to deduce some new rule but it just reinforces not to change state during render (which includes the time before the initial render, i.e. mount)

Comment: @Andru I've updated your snippet to use strict-mode like your sandbox does. As Jan points out in an answer, this is the difference causing the unexpected behavior. It is not a bug with codesandbox.

Comment: @Dexygen I think you're taking that close reason too literally. They're obviously asking why does the code render "one" instead of "two". The questions list is just a way of stating their understandings of how React works as a justification for the question.

Comment: @BrianThompson Fair enough (and I've retracted my vote), I'm just sick and tired of questions not being closed for the proper reason, actually "Needs More Focus" gets used all the time when *is not* more than one question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because react in strict mode can invoke render function multiple times before committing to DOM (similarly to react behavior in react 18 - one render doesn't mean commit). If you remove StrictMode from your app root you will see `Value: two` in the screen.
More info is at: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Comment: Because`StrictMode`only has an effect in Development (https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) the code of the OP will lead to a different results in DEV mode vs. production mode. Is this a negative side effect of `StrictMode`, i.e. a bug of `StrictMode`? I'd expect this change of behavior via the usage of `StrictMode` is not intended?

Comment: setting state inside render phase is serious violation of react roles (something like invoking hooks conditionally), so I think it is not bug in StrictMode

Answer (score 0):

As [jkaczmarkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69857198/7584643) mentions, it happens because of strict mode, which will invoke the rendering of your component twice in development, but only committing DOM changes once.

The preferred solution is to use useEffect when you want to run something once.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setValue("two");
}, []);
```

If that for some reason isn't possible you can implement a run-once behavior with a useRef. Basically you just replace your isFirstRender variable with a useRef and look at the isFirstRender.current value.

```
// Within the component...

const firstRenderRef = useRef(true);

if (firstRenderRef.current) {
    setValue("two");
    firstRenderRef.current = false;
}
```

Comment: In this case `useRef` should not be any different than a global variable, but I checked and with the `useRef` hook I indeed get `two` on the screen. 
`useRef` binds the variable to the actual component instance but since I've only got one instance in this simple example I wouldn't have expected any difference. Do you know why?

Comment: @Andru useRef works because it's a hook. React remembers the value for useRef between renders. So even if it would happen that the component invokes the render function multiple times React ensures that hooks work as expected without side effects. That's not the case with a variable outside of the component. If the render function is called multiple times react won't be able to keep track of the old value of the variable or revert it if a render is interrupted. And even if they could do that, they shouldn't, because they have no idea when and why the variable updates.